# Will fbAsyncInit() execute after the document is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have the following code from the [Facebook's developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript):

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '@SessionHelper.Current.partner.partnerVO.facebookID',
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
    xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
    version: 'v2.3' // use version 2.2
  });

  UIAuthetication.initFacebook();

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + HelperJSViewBag.getValue("Language") + "/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

This code is inside of a  tag on my header. Want I want to know if the `UIAuthetication.initFacebook();` line will be executed after all scripts of the page were loaded or if I should use `$(document).ready` to make sure that the UIAuthetication class will be available when the instruction `UIAuthetication.initFacebook();` were called.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/advanced-setup#onload: _"The function assigned to window.fbAsyncInit is run as soon as the SDK has completed loading."_

Comment: @Cbroe Só, there is a hypotheses that the SDK could load before some script had loaded right?

Comment: Yes, the SDK loads asynchronously.